# Remove error validation on focus change in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm beginner in javascript, so please bear with me.

I've a form in which i validate the controls with javascript. the error is displayed on clicking submit button when the fields are empty or where validation are not valid.

What I would like to do is to remove error message if i type in the right info in the field without clicking submit button.

```js
const paragraph = document.querySelector('p');
const form = document.getElementById('create-account-form');
const usernameInput = document.getElementById('username');

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    // btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    validateForm();
    console.log(isFormValid());
    if (isFormValid() == true) {
        form.submit();
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

});

function isFormValid() {
    const inputContainers = form.querySelectorAll('.input-group');
    let result = true;
    inputContainers.forEach((container) => {
        if (container.classList.contains('error')) {
            result = false;
        }
    });
    return result;
}

function validateForm() {
    //USERNAME
    if (usernameInput.value.trim() == '') {
        setError(usernameInput, 'Name can not be empty');
    } else if (usernameInput.value.trim().length < 5 || usernameInput.value.trim().length > 15) {
        setError(usernameInput, 'Name must be min 5 and max 15 charecters');
        usernameInput.focus();
    } else {
        document.querySelector('p').textContent = "";
        setSuccess(usernameInput);
    }
    }
    function setError(element, errorMessage) {
    const parent = element.parentElement;
    if (parent.classList.contains('success')) {
        parent.classList.remove('success');
    }
    parent.classList.add('error');
    paragraph.textContent = errorMessage;
}

function setSuccess(element) {
    const parent = element.parentElement;
    if (parent.classList.contains('error')) {
        parent.classList.remove('error');
    }
    parent.classList.add('success');
}
```

```html
<form id="create-account-form" action="result.html" method="GET">

        <div class="title">
            <h2>Create Account</h2>
        </div>
        <!-- USERNAME -->
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="username">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Name" name="username">
            <p>Error Message</p>
        </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Your code throws an error

Comment: @LukasLaudrain 1 brace was missing fixed.

Comment: When are your js functions called ?

Comment: @LukasLaudrain on the form event listener

Comment: `form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    // btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    validateForm();
    console.log(isFormValid());
    if (isFormValid() == true) {
        form.submit();
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

});`

Comment: @LukasLaudrain i have added all relevant code which is required to run, hope it helps and if you can advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `input` listener to do this.

See the codes below. I've done certain changes in the code.

modified your `<input>` as below.

```
<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Name" name="username" oninput="validateForm(this)">
```

Read more about it in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput)

```js
const paragraph = document.querySelector('p');

function isFormValid() {
    const inputContainers = form.querySelectorAll('.input-group');
    let result = true;
    inputContainers.forEach((container) => {
        if (container.classList.contains('error')) {
            result = false;
        }
    });
    return result;
}

function validateForm(usernameInput) {
    //USERNAME
    if (usernameInput.value.trim() == '') {
        setError(usernameInput, 'Name can not be empty');
    } else if (usernameInput.value.trim().length < 5 || usernameInput.value.trim().length > 15) {
        setError(usernameInput, 'Name must be min 5 and max 15 charecters');
        usernameInput.focus();
    } else {
        document.getElementById('error_p').textContent = "";
        setSuccess(usernameInput);
    }
    }
    function setError(element, errorMessage) {
    const parent = element.parentElement;
    if (parent.classList.contains('success')) {
        parent.classList.remove('success');
    }
    parent.classList.add('error');
    paragraph.textContent = errorMessage;
}

function setSuccess(element) {
    const parent = element.parentElement;
    if (parent.classList.contains('error')) {
        parent.classList.remove('error');
    }
    parent.classList.add('success');
}
```

```html
<form id="create-account-form" action="result.html" method="GET">

        <div class="title">
            <h2>Create Account</h2>
        </div>
        <!-- USERNAME -->
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="username">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Name" name="username" oninput="validateForm(this)">
            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
            <p id="error_p">Error Message</p>
        </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: it works on a single field validation but was trying to avoid it on a single field as would like to have it on the whole form. But the request is when i change the focus from username and if it is valid, it should just remove the error message.